# errException while running cloud ml engine: Unable to get element as bytes

Tags: tensorflow, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-ml

How can I solve this ?
 this error occurs when I launch prediction with cloud ml engine.

**

> Exception during running the graph: Unable to get element as bytes.

**

Comment: More information is needed. Can you provide information about the inputs to your graph (e.g. the output of saved_model_cli) as well as the JSON request that you sent?

Comment: I have 94 inputs, the same as my saved_model_cli @rhaertel80

Comment: @rhaertel80 I send you a mail with all details

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks as though one or more inputs are marked as type `DT_STRING` but you are sending non-string data. Although I didn't go through all of the columns, I did notice at least the following:

```
inputs['dos_cp_trav'] tensor_info:
    dtype: DT_STRING
    shape: (-1)
    name: Placeholder_43:0
```

And your input JSON contained:

```
{
  ...
  "dos_cp_trav": 13009
  ...
}
```

You need to either change the data type of "dos_cp_trav" or pass a string in the JSON.

There may be others as well, so I recommend you double check the data types of all the inputs. You'll probably also find it helpful to use `gcloud ml-engine local predict --json-instance=FILE` to test locally before sending of large jobs to the cloud.

Comment: I'll double check that, thanks for your answer @rhaertel80

Comment: Thanks again, it was my json the problem, I use  this https://www.csvjson.com/csv2json to transform my csv to json, that's why ...